# Golang converting float64 to int error

Tags: go, floating-point, precision

How can I avoid floating point errors when converting float's to int's. 
For example the following code prints: `0.5499999999999972` when I wound expect it to print `0.55`.

```
package main

import "fmt"

func main() {
    x := 100.55
    fmt.Println(x - float64(int(x)))    
}

Output:
0.5499999999999972
```

Comment: Try `100.55 - 100` in a Python or Ruby REPL.  I get `0.5499999999999972` in both those cases as well.  Are you familiar with gotchas in floating point arithmetic?

Comment: Hi, I'm not 100% on how to avoid floating point errors. Any advice?

Comment: Are you familiar with gotchas in floating point arithmetic?

Comment: Anything wrong with `fmt.Printf` ?

Comment: [What Every Computer Scientist Should Know About Floating-Point Arithmetic](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19957-01/806-3568/ncg_goldberg.html)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to understand something: `100.55` is a decimal number (presented in decimal radix). `100.55` in decimal is a finite number and is exactly this: `100.55`.

Computers in general store numbers in binary representation. The number `100.55` cannot be represented with a finite binary number: `100.55` is an *infinite* number in binary representation (same reason why `1/3` cannot be represented with a finite decimal number, it is an endless sequence: `0.333333333....`).

But Go (like any other language) stores `float64` types using the [IEEE-754](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point) standard, which is a finite *binary* representation. A `float64` value uses 64 bits in memory to describe the number, of which 53 bits are used to describe the digits and 11 bits are used for the exponent.

Now when you "say" this:

```
x := 100.55
```

It is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations) which will create a new variable named `x` and infer its type from the right hand side expression which is a floating point literal, so by the Go spec `x`'s type will be `float64`. The floating point literal will have to be "converted" in order to be represented using 64 bits (by rules specified by `IEEE-754`). And since `100.55` would require infinite bits to be represented precisely in binary radix, by using only 64 bits (53 for the digits) the result will not (cannot) be exactly `100.55` (but a 64-bit binary number in IEEE-754 format that is closest to it), which is:

```
x := 100.55
fmt.Printf("%.50f\n", x)

100.54999999999999715782905695959925651550292968750000
```

So you are already starting off with a number not being `100.55`.

You subtract `100` from it (`float64(int(x))` will be exactly `100.0`):

```
x = x - float64(int(x))
fmt.Printf("%.50f\n", x)

0.54999999999999715782905695959925651550292968750000
```

What can you do about it? Nothing really. The result you expect (`0.55`) is also an infinite number in binary representation, so you can't have an exact number of `0.55` in a variable of type `float64`.

What you can do is work with the number as normal, but when you print it, round it to decimal places of your choice. The easiest is to use [`fmt.Printf()`](https://golang.org/pkg/fmt/#Printf), and specify a format string using the verb `%f` including the precision:

```
fmt.Printf("%.2f\n", x)
```

Result:

```
0.55
```

Another option is to avoid using floating point numbers. E.g. if you were to represent USD amounts, you could "multiply" all your values by `100` and represent amounts as cents (1$*100) which is an integer. Only if you need to print the result as USD, you could print something like

```
cents := 10055
fmt.Printf("%d.%d $", cents/100, cents%100)
```

Output:

```
100.55 $
```