# Sleeping by Fractions of a Time Duration

Tags: go, time, types, type-conversion, constants

Can someone tell me why this works:

```
s := time.Hour/73.0
fmt.Println("sleeping: ", s)
time.Sleep(s)
```

But this fails:

```
d := 73.0
s := time.Hour/d
fmt.Println("sleeping: ", s)
time.Sleep(s)
```

This is the error:

```
invalid operation: time.Hour / d (mismatched types time.Duration and float64)
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This line:

```
s := time.Hour/73.0
```

Is a [short variable declaration](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Short_variable_declarations), where the right hand side expression is: `time.Hour / 73.0`. `time.Hour` is a typed constant from the [`time`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/) package, its type is [`time.Duration`](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Duration); and `73.0` is an *untyped numeric constant* which when used in an expression, will take the appropriate type if possible. Since `time.Duration` has `int64` as its underlying type, the constant `73.0` can be converted to `time.Duration` without loss of precision, so that will happen, and the constant expression `time.Hour / time.Duration(73.0)` will be executed.

The other line:

```
d := 73.0
s := time.Hour/d
```

The first line is a short variable declaration, where the type of `d` will be inferred from the right hand side expression, which is an untyped numeric constant (given with a [floating point literal](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Floating-point_literals) to be exact). Since a type is needed, its default type will be used, which is `float64`. So `d` will be a variable of type `float64`.

The short variable declaration in the next line: `time.Hour / d`, here `time.Hour` is again a value of type `time.Duration`, but you attempt to divide it by a value of type `float64`, that is not allowed in Go.

To make it work, you have to explicitly convert `d` to `time.Duration`:

```
s := time.Hour / time.Duration(d)
```

Or `d` must be of type `time.Duration`:

```
d := time.Duration(73.0)
s := time.Hour / d
```

Or:

```
var d time.Duration = 73.0
s := time.Hour / d
```

These wouldn't work if the value cannot be represented with `time.Duration`, for example `73.5` (because `time.Duration` has `int64` underlying type). In this case you have to convert `time.Hour` to `float64`, perform the division and convert the result to `time.Duration`, e.g.:

```
d := 73.5
s := time.Duration(float64(time.Hour) / d)
```

Read more details on the topic:

[Spec: Constants](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants)

[The Go Blog: Constants](https://blog.golang.org/constants)

[Why does 0.1 + 0.2 get 0.3 in Google Go?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42153747/why-does-0-1-0-2-get-0-3-in-google-go/42154298#42154298)

[How does Go perform arithmetic on constants?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38982278/how-does-go-perform-arithmetic-on-constants/38982889#38982889)

[Golang converting float64 to int error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36052922/golang-converting-float64-to-int-error/36055172#36055172)

Comment: Thanks very much for the the detailed answer and links to further reading. I learned a lot from this!