# Confused with Type conversions in golang

Tags: go

I recently tried to learn golang. But I got confused with this code from https://tour.golang.org/basics/13.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "math"
)

func main() {
    var x, y int = 3, 4
    var f float64 = math.Sqrt(float64(x*x + y*y))
    var z uint = uint(f)
    fmt.Println(x, y, z)
}
```

That one works well. Then I tried

var f = math.Sqrt(9 + 16)

which also works. But when I change it to `var f = math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y)` why is it not working? It says `cannot use x * x + y * y (type int) as type float64 in argument to math.Sqrt`

I have javascript background, and I somehow can't understand the code above.

Comment: Related / possible duplicate of [Sleeping by Fractions of a Time Duration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42605412/sleeping-by-fractions-of-a-time-duration/42606191#42606191).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The [math.Sqrt](https://golang.org/pkg/math/#Sqrt) function signature:

```
func Sqrt(x float64) float64
```

requires that you pass `float64`

In this case:

```
var f float64 = math.Sqrt(float64(x*x + y*y))
```

You are converting to `float64` directly

In this case:

```
var f = math.Sqrt(x*x + y*y)
```

you are passing an `int`, when `float64` is required.

In this case:

```
var f = math.Sqrt(9 + 16)
```

The compiler is able to infer the type, and pass `float64` for you.

Comment: So when pass a variable which has value a number, the compiler doesn't convert it automatically? But when we pass a number directly, it automatically converted?

Comment: @muhajir, basically yes, when you pass in a variable, `x` and `y` that were explicitly declared as `int`, which is not a `float64`, so the compiler rejects that. When you pass in a number directly, the compiler checks the function signatures and sees if the input is valid for a `float64` and it is, much like this is valid: `var x float64 = 4`

Answer (score 4):

> But when we pass a number directly, it automatically converted?

No, not really *). Your "direct numbers" are called "constants" in Go and constants are often "untyped" and (almost) of arbitrary precision. There are special rules for constants: A constant `5` and the integer `a` defined by `a := 5` behave differently because `5` is a constant with special rules and not an `int`.

Constant expressions like `9 + 16` are evaluated at *compile* *time* like if you had typed `25`. This `25` is still a (constant.

While Go does not have automatic type conversions for types it *does* *have* automatic conversions from constants to several types. The constant `25` can be converted to float64 or int, uint8 or even complex128 automatically.

Please read the blog post https://blog.golang.org/constants and the official language spec for a full explanation and all details: https://golang.org/ref/spec#Constants . This explains the strange notion of
"untyped integer" better than I could.

*) "not really" because it is not helpful to think about it that way. The distinction of constants is special in Go: Most other languages tread 3+5 as a sum of two ints resulting in an int while Go sees two untyped integer constants and evaluates this expression into a new arbitrary precision, untyped constant. Only later are constants converted to actual integers.